# How to stop being a burning snowman?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Just to make this clear, this is *not* my usual avatar on GTA online.

I was playing a recent game and went into a quick mission, but when I entered the game with 3 other random players, I looked like this:

[image: Why am I a snowman with a fire]

This is not my avatar and somehow a snowman has been added over, in addition a camp fire, which is constantly burning me until I die (the only reason I am not currently is because I am in my garage.) I am not sure but my account may have been hacked. Any help on how I can stop constantly burning and revert my character to my original avatar (without burning)?

Comment: I had a similar problem, except it was a friend who was stuck as a UFO.  Incredibly difficult to drive when all you see is grey.  I'm not sure if they restarted the game or if they just had to go to a different server.